# how to get elasticsearch documents in custom order

Tags: elasticsearch

Is there any way to get documents from elasticsearch in custom order .

the documents in elastic are indexed like this :

```
{
 "productId":1
},
{
 "productId":2
},
{
 "productId":3
}
```

i need to get documents in order as term query order

i try this query but not work :

```
{  
   "from":0,
   "size":20,
   "query":{  
      "bool":{  
         "should":[  
            {  
               "term":{  
                  "productId":{  
                     "value":3,
                     "boost":1.0
                  }
               }
            },
            {  
               "term":{  
                  "productId":{  
                     "value":1,
                     "boost":1.0
                  }
               }
            },
            {  
               "term":{  
                  "productId":{  
                     "value":2,
                     "boost":1.0
                  }
               }
            }
         ],
         "adjust_pure_negative":true,
         "boost":1.0
      }
   },
   "version":true
}
```

as you see term queries with productId:3 , productId:1 , productId:2

i expect result are documents sorted as term queries order :

```
{
 "productId":3
},
{
 "productId":1
},
{
 "productId":2
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand the requirement here.

Comment: i have updated my question please take a look

Comment: Still not clear, but let me try. Change the boost value for each `term` to match the importance of each product (and thus giving a better score to the documents for products higher in the list)?

Comment: do you have same way using mongodb ??

Comment: I have no knowledge about MongoDB.